# Insert Query not working in code while the same is running in the query browser ??? MYSQL Java Code

Tags: java, mysql, insert, insert-update

hi i am trying to insert data in table  my code is,

```
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    InsertData="INSERT INTO  nagios.authors VALUES ('1','1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1','2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929','2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','','/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 192.168.1.106 -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5','30','0','4.04159','0.102','1','PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms','','rta=2.860000ms;3000.000000;5000.000000;0.000000pl=0%;80;100;0');";
    html.append("Data Inserted : "+ GetUpdate(InsertData) );
    return html 
}

        public int GetUpdate(String sql)
        {        
           int rs = dbOperation.DbupdateStatement(con,sql);      
            return rs;
        }

        public int DbupdateStatement(Connection con,String command)
        {
            int status =0;
            if (con != null)
            {
                try
                {
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                String sql=command;
                //status = stmt.executeUpdate(command);
                return stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return status;

        }
```

first method is returning html on jsp to print the return value of the "executeupdate" while the query is passing to the Getupdate and then DbUpdateStatement method to execute query while the con os the connection to which i am connecting to database and have full writes to create and update database my this method is not inserting value ??

Hopes for your suggestions...

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I hope you know what JavaBeans naming convention is.

Comment: Use PrepareStatement and release JDBC resources property.

Comment: no i am not getting any error ! and i have wrriten any thing incorrect naming convention ???

Comment: @AVD how to use preparestatement ?? please arange it for my code?

Comment: INSERT INTO  nagios.authors change to INSERT INTO  authors

Comment: i have use after removing schema name also but result is same :(

Comment: You don't get any error messages if you are using empty catch blocks. use ex.printStacktrace() function inside the catch block and then after running the query check your server log files.

Comment: and put an else block also inside DbupdateStatement() method and print some error message to check whether connection is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
InsertData="INSERT INTO  authors VALUES ('1','1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1','2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929','2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','','/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 192.168.1.106 -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5','30','0','4.04159','0.102','1','PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms','','rta=2.860000ms;3000.000000;5000.000000;0.000000pl=0%;80;100;0');";
```

You don't need to specify schema name with table name in MySql database. schema name is written only in Query Browser.

Comment: i am creating table before inserting the values in it so for that also i use schema name before table name in query i use in cade and it is working correctly !

Answer (score 0):

You should release JDBC resoures when they are no longer needed in your code and write parameter sql statement.

```
String sql="INSERT INTO TableName (col1,col2,col3) values (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps=null;
try{
 ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setString(1,"String_value for col1");
 ps.setInt(2,10); // set int value to col2 if it is int type
 ps.setString(3,"something");
 ps.executeUpdate();
}catch(Exception ex) {

}finally {
  if(ps!=null) ps.close();
  if(con!=null) con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing my guess.... can you try to remove or skip the comma in one of the value in below..may the comma is breaking your query...

```
'/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 192.168.1.106 -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the autocommit setting in you mysql database. Or commit explicitly.
`con.commit`

Answer (score 0):

1. `catch(Exception ex){}`
   print the exception stack trace.by adding

   ex.printStacktrace();
   you may get exception details and then you may fix.

2.another thing

```
INSERT INTO  nagios.authors VALUES ('1','1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1','2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929','2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','','/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H 192.168.1.106 -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5','30','0','4.04159','0.102','1','PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms','','rta=2.860000ms;3000.000000;5000.000000;0.000000pl=0%;80;100;0');";
```

does it include all columns of the table,please check.

3.please check wether sql query successfully inserts data into table by manualing running on
sql editor.

Comment: add ex.printStacktrace() to your catch statement to see if u get any errors.

Comment: try removing extra ; in query